# Keeping the max values in python list

Tags: python

I have a list of increasing numbers. It's building up to a maximum and then suddenly dropping and building up again.
For example:
`[16.5, 20.5, 32.5, 32.5, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.5, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 6.0, 8.5, 6.5, 6.5, 11.0, 14.0, 14.0, 8.5, 12.0, 21.0, 25.0, 25.0, 37.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0]`

What I would like to do is keep the maximums surrounded by lower (or the same) value.
So in this case the result would be
`[41.0, 8.5, 14.0, 38.0]`

Of course the last value is provisional because if the one after 38.0 would be 39.0 then 39.0 would be the new value which is then kept in the list after a new drop/lower value. This lower value would be the new (provisional) last item.

Any help would be appreciated!
Ivo

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `[41, 8.5, 14, 38]`?  There's `6.5, 8.5, 6.5` in there. :)

Comment: correct. Will edit. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A generator like this might do the trick:

```
def detect_peaks(data):
    last_value = None
    for value in data:
        if last_value is not None and value < last_value:
            yield last_value
        last_value = value
    yield value


print(list(detect_peaks(my_list)))
```

outputs

```
[41.0, 8.5, 14.0, 38.0]
```

for the `my_list` presented in the question.

Since it's a generator, you can use it lazily as well; `for peak in detect_peaks(...): ...`.

Comment: Thanks, but something tells me it could be quicker.

Comment: What's too slow about this? I can't think of a faster pure-Python way off the top of my head.

Comment: There's no way of doing what the OP wants in less than O(n) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the very popular `scipy` package like this:

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = [16.5, 20.5, 32.5, 32.5, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.5, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 6.0, 8.5, 6.5, 6.5, 11.0, 14.0, 14.0, 8.5, 12.0, 21.0, 25.0, 25.0, 37.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0]

def get_peaks(list_):
    list_copy = list_.copy()
    list_copy.insert(0, list_copy[0] - 1)  # To catch any peaks at the start
    list_copy.append(list_copy[-1] - 1)  # To catch any peaks at the end
    return [list_copy[i] for i in find_peaks(list_copy)[0]]

get_peaks(x)

>>> [41.0, 8.5, 14.0, 38.0]
```

`pip install scipy`

It doesn't catch peaks at the start or end so by inserting and appending values we can catch those too, not ideal tbh.

Comment: That seems to be missing the final `38`...

Comment: (Also, a quick benchmark shows this is about 4x slower than my `detect_peaks` for OP's data. I suspect it could be faster for larger data.)

Comment: Added a fix to catch peaks at the start and end. Yeah yours is much better @AKX

Answer (score 0):

a simple method like this will do the thing in your case:

```
for i in range(1,len(array)):
    if array[i-1] > array[i]:
        maxes.append(array[i-1])
    if i == len(array)-1:
        maxes.append(array[i])
print(maxes)
```

i did everythings with array and array methods for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it :

```
def find_maximums(values):
    maximums = []
    previous_v = min(values)
    for v in values:
        if v < previous_v:
            maximums.append(previous_v)
        previous_v = v
    maximums.append(previous_v)
    return maximums
```

output :

> [41.0, 8.5, 14.0, 38.0]

Might not be the smartest way but at least it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution, but this requires you to run on Python 3.10+ ([pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) was introduced in 3.10):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, pairwise
>>> [i for i, j in pairwise(chain(lst, [float('-inf')])) if i > j]
[41.0, 8.5, 14.0, 38.0]
```

Relatively fast solution:

```
def peaks(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    front = next(it, None)
    if front is None:
        return
    for back in it:
        if front > back:
            yield front
        front = back
    yield front

>>> list(peaks(lst))
[41.0, 8.5, 14.0, 38.0]

%timeit [i for i, j in pairwise(chain(lst, [float('-inf')])) if i > j]
2.84 µs ± 29.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit list(peaks(lst))
1.67 µs ± 38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Still slower (`8.01 µs ± 168 ns per loop`) than @AKX implementation (`427 ns ± 5.82 ns per loop`).

Comment: @A259 I didn't say that this is the fastest solution, and you only tested the construction time of his generator function, without converting it into a list.

Comment: My bad, time with list construction is `5.71 µs ± 629 ns per loop`